# Проблема с QSettings (Qt 5.4)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

```
#include <QSettings>


----------


QSettings settings;
settings.setValue("time_axis_direction", 1);
int test_var = settings.value("time_axis_direction").toInt();


----------
```

В переменную `test_var` кладётся значение 0, в чём может быть причина?
В *Qt4* всё работало корректно; *Qt5* не собрано, а подключено через *VS Add-In*.

**Обновление**

В оригинале `settings` - член класса, значения ключей присваиваются в методах класса, конструктор `settings` вызывается в конструкторе данного класса:

```
Controller::Controller(ImagesMaker *i, Ui_Mainwindow *v, QObject *parent) :
    settings(QSettings::SystemScope, "SC", "CV", this)
```

В самом деле, `status()` возвращает ошибку доступа. Не подскажете, что можно с этим сделать?

Comment: А это точный код, который воспроизводит багу? у меня он прекрасно работает и выводит ожидаемое значение.

Есть смутное подозрение, что пишет то оно в виндах в реестр, а у приложения просто нет прав.

Comment: я бы для начала использовал QSettings::UserScope, потому что в глобальном уже вполне может быть приложение с именем sc (какой нибудь service controller). И имя организации взял бы чуточку подлинее, а не sc.

Comment: @KoVadim имя организации и приложения длиннее на самом деле, я сократила для комментария (видимо, только внесла путаницу, извините)

Comment: @KoVadim QSettings::UserScope работает, спасибо

Comment: @KoVadim Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QSettings в случае винды по умолчанию сохраняет настройки в реестре. А обычному приложению без прав администратора мало куда можно писать. `QSettings::SystemScope` пишет в место, которое доступно всем пользователям. Если какой то другой пользователь уже туда записал, а права нормально не выставил, то может быть плохо.

`QSettings::UserScope` - как по мне, это более красивый и правильный вариант. Настройки будут сохраняться в специальной ветке реестра, которая доступна только для текущего пользователя (и администратора, который знает, как это сделать). К этому разделу у текущего пользователя обычно полные права. Да и другим пользователям на компьютере не будет мешать.

Answer (score 0):

У меня заработало при таком варианте записи:

```
auto settings = new QSettings(QSettings::NativeFormat,
                         QSettings::UserScope,
                         "QApplication::organizationName()",
                         "QApplication::applicationName()");
settings->setValue("first_start", "true");
qDebug() << settings->value("first_start").toString()
```